# Cálculo de derivadas em Java

Tags: java, matemática

Olá, boa dia.

Estou aqui pedindo uma luz para um problema que tenho, meu professor de programação pediu para que fizessemos um código que calcule a derivada de uma função em java, mas estou sem um norte para iniciar o código, alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Eu já pesquisei e até vi alguns códigos, mas não satisfazem os requisitos que o professor pediu. Agradeço desde já à todos.

Comment: Comece procurando pelos métodos numéricos de derivação.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Não intereprete erradamente o que eu vou dizer, mas se não sabe nem como começar é porque ainda não está na altura certa para embarcar nesse desafio. Tem de voltar atrás e estudar as partes mais iniciais de programação e depois garantir que sabe bem como derivar em matemática.

Comment: O que eu faria é ler a função dada, tipo x^2, e a partir daí ir implementando a função pouco a pouco. Comece fazendo as derivadas mais simples sozinhas, depois agrupe-as, e vá dificultando progressivamente.

Comment: Normalmente quando pensamos em derivação vem à cabeça a simbólica (que é a que fazemos no papel) e o Java não possui pacotes nativos para isso. Talvez ele não possa usar APIs então derivar simbolicamente fica difícil. Se puder usar veja essa: https://github.com/yuemingl/SymJava